# How to kill sharks whilst underwater?

Tags: assassins-creed-odyssey

I find fighting sharks whilst underwater one of the biggest challenges in the game. I have taken to employing the Assassins Creed Black Flag technique of hiding from them instead of engaging them.

Is there a sound and reliable tactic for dealing with sharks?

Comment: It tooks me a while until I figured out I can swim up and shoot sharks from water surface. Was sure I have to be *standing* on something, but no - you can swim to surface and shoot all sharks while swimming, then dive, loot, etc. Easy. No challenge. Random quest to kill sharks is common.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## The easiest way to fight sharks while underwater is to *avoid fighting sharks while underwater*

Whenever you plan to do some deep sea diving, send out Ikaros first to spot any sharks you might run into. Then, just pick them off from the surface with your physically unrealistic bow. I've had this work with sharks of any depth.

## If you find yourself face to face with a shark, maximize your range

Make sure you have a quick weapon with length (like a spear or staff) that can hit/stun a shark before it makes contact with you. That's usually enough to stave off an attack and force them to circle for another pass at you.

Also, if you find yourself surrounded, quickly changing your vertical position (moving up or down) is a more effective way of dodging then just moving horizontally.

Comment: Icarus tip is handy. You have to spot all (most) enemies before fight begun always (unless you are sure what fight is easy, underwater shark fight is not). But suggesting to say underwater is bad idea. Too high risk. I hate save system in Odyssey, where you lose all progress from last check point. It's the reason I stop playing it and wrote [negative review](https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561197990188583/recommended/812140) on Steam. In another words - don't take unnecessary risk.